# Script Azure AD B2C [DevOps]

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to be able to create a script in C# that would create a Azure AD B2C container. The goals would be to create a C# application with parameters that I could execute and create a the B2C directory for a SAAS application. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like automating the creation of an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant is not  supported.

The documentation points to [Tutorial: Create an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant), which only shows how to do so through the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

**EDIT:**
Even the article [Azure AD B2C: Use the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet), which explains how to use an API to manage an Azure AD B2C tenant, links to the article above that helps you manually create a B2C tenant.

Comment: Thanks @rickvdbosch

Comment: Did you find a solution to that?